# How to decide whether the result of an integer expression is an integer

Tags: c++, c, math, integer

I have an expression of `n` like `(30 - n(n - 1)) / 2n`. And I want search the possible n which will be my answer only when the result is an integer. Is there any way to decide whether the result of this expression is an integer or not.

The only way that I can come up with is(in pseudo code ) :

```
for float n <- 1 to 100
  do float result = expression(n);
     int part = (int) result;
     if ( result - part < EPS )
       then good to go
```

Comment: Why do you declare n as a float ?

Comment: because if it is an `int`, the expression will be an ineger. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sure but then you can use integer remainder to see if the division in exact !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `%` to compute the remainder.

```
int denom = 2 * n;
int numer = 30 - n * (n - 1);

if (denom) {
    if (numer % denom == 0) {
        then good to go
    }
} else {
    /*...denominator is 0! */
}
```

Comment: That won't work so well for `n == 0` :-) But since OP stated `n` ranges from `1` to `100`, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: A divide by 0 exception is as good as an assertion, but you are right that it would be friendlier to test for a non-zero denominator.

Answer (score 2):

`if (30 - n(n - 1)) mod 2n equals to zero`

Answer (score 1):

If `modf` returns `0.0`, the floating point number it is called
on is an integer.  This is the standard way of testing whether
a floating point number is an integer; it works with *all*
floating point values, even those that would overflow an `int`.